Let a group $G=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&a\end{pmatrix} : a,b\in\mathbb{Z_3}, a\neq{0}\right\}$. Find the order of $G$ and find all subgroups
First, I observed that $G$ has finite elements (let $n$) which implies that $|G|= n$. We can easily see that $n=1\cdot3+1\cdot3=6$, since we have $2$ values for $0\neq{a}\in{Z_3}$ and $3$ values for $b\in\mathbb{Z_3}$. Then as a check, I did the whole process to find the minimum $k\in\mathbb{Z}: g^k=1_G=I_2$ $\forall{g}\in{G}$. Basically I randomized $b\in\mathbb{Z_3}$ and took 2 cases for $a=[1]_3$ and $a=[2]_3$,where every element of the form $\begin{pmatrix}1&b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}2&b\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$ respectively has order of 6.
Now I'm stuck to find all subgroups of G as given. Any hints or solutions for the latter would be appreciated.

So the group has $6$ elements and you've identified two generators of the group, mean it's cyclic. Can you find the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$?

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  When $b=[0]_3$, the order of $\pmatrix{1&b\0&1}$ is $1$, not $6$

Observe that $\pmatrix{1&b\0&1}\pmatrix{2&b\0&2}=\pmatrix{2&b\0&2}\pmatrix{1&b\0&1}$, and there is only one commutative group of order $6$ up to isomorphism

The order of $$\pmatrix{1&b\cr0&1\cr},$$ $b\neq0$, is surely three. Meaning that it generates a proper subgroup...

The order of $\pmatrix{2&0\0&2}$ is two...

@J.W.Tanner just noticed so? what do I answer?

There is a subgroup of every order dividing $6$

After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: How do I accept an answer?, Why should we accept answers?, What should I do if someone answers my question?.

We can easily see that the elements of the group $G$ are $\{ x_1 = \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{matrix}\right), x_2 = \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{matrix}\right), x_3 = \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 2\\0 & 1\end{matrix}\right), x_4 = \left(\begin{matrix}2 & 0\\0 & 2\end{matrix}\right), x_5 = \left(\begin{matrix}2 & 1\\0 & 2\end{matrix}\right),x_6 = \left(\begin{matrix}2 & 2\\0 & 2\end{matrix}\right)\}$. By simple observation we get that $ord(x_1) = 1, ord(x_2) = ord(x_3) = 3, ord(x_4) = 2$ and $ord(x_5) = ord(x_6) = 6$.
Now, since order of element divides the order of a finite group and order of a subgroup divides the order of a group, the non-trivial subgroups of $G$ have size either 2 or 3. Say $G_1$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order 2, then $G_1 = \{x_1, y\}$. But since order of element divides order of group, the only element in $G$ which is not equal to $x_1$ and also whose order divides 2 is $x_4$. So, the only subgroup of order 2 is $G_1 = \{x_1,x_4\}$. Now, similarly let $G_2 = \{x_1, y, z\}$ be a subgroup of order 3. By the similar arguments above, the only possible values for $y$ and $z$ are $x_2$ and $x_3$. So, $G_2 = \{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$ is the only possible subgroup of order 3. It can also be seen that these are exactly the cyclic groups generated by $x_4$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ (same as the one generated by $x_2$). So, there are no non-cyclic subgroups of $G$ as well. As pointed out by J. W. Tanner in the comments, $G$ is a cyclic group.

Let $X=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}.$ Observe that $|X|=6$ and $X$ generates the group $G$. Hence $G\cong \Bbb Z_6$.

Theorem: Let $G$ be a finite, cyclic group. Suppose $d\mid |G|$. Then there exists exactly one subgroup of $G$ of order $d$.

Indeed, the subgroup lattice of $\Bbb Z_6$ looks like
$$\begin{array}{c}
 \Bbb Z_6 \\
 /  \,\setminus \\
\Bbb Z_2 \,\,\,\,\, \Bbb Z_3\\
 \setminus \, /\\
\{ e\} 
\end{array}$$
From this information, you will find the subgroups.
